# Add external jars globally

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

Is there any way to add an jar file globally so that anyone can use it without configuring build paths again and again?

I have a external jar so when I import it it will look like this

```
C:\Users\Username\Path\external.jar
```

Can I add it like

```
ProjectPath\external.jar
```

So that users in my github repo don't need to reconfigure again and again.

Comment: Use _Add JARs..._ instead of _Add External JARs..._ for project-internal JARs.

Comment: @howlger It worked Thanks! Please post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use ***Add JARs...*** instead of *Add External JARs...* for project-internal JARs.

Alternatively, you can use Maven or Gradle so that the JARs don't have to be part of the project.